# Unable to access json object in javascript return

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

When i am trying to get json type data in return of an ajax call,i am getting undefined as return.

```
function AjaxCallToGetData(){
    var chartDataCheckin;
    var checkin_location = $("#select_checkin_location").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        'url': '<?php echo $this->modurl; ?>dashboard/checkinchart',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {checkin_location: checkin_location},
        'type': 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);     // alerts object  

            return data;
        }
    });

}
function getcheckinchart(DataCheckin) {
    alert('hi');
    var chartDataCheckin = AjaxCallToGetData();
    alert(chartDataCheckin); // this doesnot
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var testobj;
function AjaxCallToGetData(){
        var chartDataCheckin;
        var checkin_location = $("#select_checkin_location").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            'url': '<?php echo $this->modurl; ?>dashboard/checkinchart',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {checkin_location: checkin_location},
            'type': 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);     // alerts object  

               testobj=data;
            }
        });

    }
    function getcheckinchart(DataCheckin) {
        alert('hi');
         AjaxCallToGetData();
        alert(testobj); 
        }
```

This will work :)Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the data from an async call to the server but you are expecting the return in a sync way. Use a global variable or use a Deferred Object or a Promise: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is located in the success callback of the (asynchronous) AJAX action, so it isn't returned as result of AjaxCallToGetData().

The solution:

Either do your processing in the success callback or create your own callback. I myself am partial to dynamic callbacks so I included a basic example where I pass the callback function as a parameter.

```
function AjaxCallToGetData(callback){
    var chartDataCheckin;
    var checkin_location = $("#select_checkin_location").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->modurl; ?>dashboard/checkinchart',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {checkin_location: checkin_location},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // Either process the data here or:
            if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) callback(data);
        }
    });
}

function getcheckinchart(DataCheckin) {
    // Notice we're passing the callback function as a parameter
    AjaxCallToGetData(processcheckinchart);
}

function processcheckinchart(data) {
    alert(data);     // alerts object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the ajax call is asynchronous so when you alert in the `getcheckinchart` the data are not still there. This should work.

```
 function AjaxCallToGetData(callback){
        var chartDataCheckin;
        var checkin_location = $("#select_checkin_location").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            'url': '<?php echo $this->modurl; ?>dashboard/checkinchart',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {checkin_location: checkin_location},
            'type': 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);     // alerts object  

                callback(null,data);
            }
        });

    }
    function getcheckinchart(DataCheckin) {
        alert('hi');
        AjaxCallToGetData(function(err,charDataCheckin){
            alert(chartDataCheckin); 
        });
        }
```